# Help Center header seems to have gone missing

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, help-center, tour

One of my fellow moderators noticed that [the Help Center for our site](https://ham.stackexchange.com/help) no longer has a banner at the top linking to the Tour.

A little browsing around and use of the Wayback Machine indicates that this change has just happened across *all* sites (that I've checked), [even Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/help) Smells like a bug.

Comment: I still see the banner for the tour?

Comment: Agreed. *It needs to be changed back to the way it was*.

Comment: @Catija It's not on https://ham.stackexchange.com/help.

Comment: I think they just made it so that if you've taken the tour, you don't see the banner any more. View the page in incognito mode. I **definitely** see the banner still, though... on your site. On the site I mod, It is gone... unless I view the page when I'm not logged in.

Comment: @MikeWaters Why? What's wrong with only showing it to people who haven't taken the tour?

Comment: Nothing. I just didn't realize that! Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that, if you've taken the tour already, you don't have to stare at the banner any more.

I also moderate a site and I saw that the same thing happened on my site but when I view the site when I'm not logged in (in an incognito browser window), the banner is back where it should have been.

View when logged in:

[image: View when logged in]

View when logged out:

[image: View when logged out]

To assuage your fears, this is what I see when I'm on Amateur Radio's Help Center page:

[image: Amateur Radio Help Center page with tour banner]

As such, I'm going to guess this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Comment: Perfect. Nice change.

Answer (score 6):

Almost no one ever clicked that link if they already had an account; heck, barely anyone clicks it *period*, but at least anonymous viewers manage to break 2%, while less than half a percent of logged-in viewers bothered.

Arguably the tour isn't particularly useful if you already know what you're looking for.

So, henceforth it'll appear for anonymous users and not anyone else.